# How can i make the Jbutton in my widgetviewer to implement the proper event

Tags: java, swing, widget, jbutton, numberformatexception

Instructions:

```
Write a WidgetViewer GUI that has the following widgets:

a button labeled "go up/down"
a label initialized to 0 (we'll call this the left label)
a label initialized to 0 (we'll call this the right label)
a button labeled "go down/up"

When the "go up/down" button is pushed, a random number between 1 and 10 (inclusive)
is generated and added to the left label, and another random number between 1 and 10 (inclusive)
is generated and subtracted from the right label.

When the "go down/up" button is pushed, a random number between 1 and 10 (inclusive) is
generated and subtracted from the left label, and another random number between 1 and 10
(inclusive) is generated and added to the right label.
```

Error msg:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Go up/down"
```

Code:

I cant seem to figure out this error message, it might have a possibility that i am adding a string but im not sure, it may be my logic. But im trying to figure out how i can get the Jbutton called goupdown and godownup to display a random number then add or subtract by 1 if needed.

```
public class UpAndDown {


    public UpAndDown() {

    WidgetViewer wv = new WidgetViewer();
    JButton goUpDown = new JButton("Go up/down");
    JLabel leftLabel = new JLabel("0");
    wv.add(goUpDown, 10, 30, 150, 20);
    wv.add(leftLabel, 10, 60, 150, 25);

    JButton goDownUp = new JButton("Go down/up");
    JLabel rightLabel = new JLabel("0");
    wv.add(goDownUp, 10, 120, 150, 20);
    wv.add(rightLabel, 10, 160, 150, 25);

    ButtonIncrement action = new ButtonIncrement(goUpDown);
    goUpDown.addActionListener(action);

    ButtonIncrement action2 = new ButtonIncrement(goDownUp);
    goDownUp.addActionListener(action2);
}

static class ButtonIncrement implements ActionListener {

    private final JButton goUpDownBtn;
    private final JButton goDownUpBtn;

    public ButtonIncrement(JButton buttonToModify) {
        goUpDownBtn = buttonToModify;
        goDownUpBtn = buttonToModify;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        String val = goUpDownBtn.getText();
        //JButton jc = (JButton) e.getSource();
        int newVal = Integer.parseInt(val) + rand;
        goDownUpBtn.setText(String.valueOf(newVal));
        //jc.setText(goDownUpBtn.getText() + " " + val);// get string, convert to int, add rand value. then convert int back to string and set text to string

        /*String val2 = goDownUpBtn.getText();
        int newVal2 = Integer.parseInt(val2) + rand;
        goDownUpBtn.setText(String.valueOf(newVal2));*/


    }
}
```

Comment: The error is self expiatory - you can't convert the text `"Go up/down"` to a number.  What you "should" be doing is maintaining the "left value" and "right value" as independent properties which you can interact with based on the event which is triggered

Comment: * explanatory  ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified code:

I modified the answer you gave according to the instructions with the WV object to display the GUI and this is the correct version.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;



public class UpAndDown extends JPanel {

private JLabel leftLabel;
private JLabel rightLabel;

private JButton upDownButton;
private JButton downUpButton;


public UpAndDown() {


    WidgetViewer wv = new WidgetViewer();

    JButton upDownButton  = new JButton("Up/down");
    wv.add(upDownButton, 10, 30, 150, 20);
    JButton downUpButton = new JButton("Down/up");
    wv.add(downUpButton, 10, 120, 150, 20);

    JLabel leftLabel = new JLabel("0");
    wv.add(leftLabel, 10, 60, 150, 25);
    JLabel rightLabel = new JLabel("0");
    wv.add(rightLabel, 10, 140, 150, 25);

    upDownButton.setActionCommand("upDown");
    downUpButton.setActionCommand("downUp");

    ActionListener actionListener = new IncrementDecrementAction(leftLabel, rightLabel);

    upDownButton.addActionListener(actionListener);
    downUpButton.addActionListener(actionListener);

}

static class IncrementDecrementAction implements ActionListener {

    private final JLabel leftLabel;
    private final JLabel rightLabel;

    private int leftValue = 0;
    private int rightValue = 0;

    public IncrementDecrementAction(JLabel leftLabel, JLabel rightLabel) {
        this.leftLabel = leftLabel;
        this.rightLabel = rightLabel;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        int leftRandom = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        int rightRandom = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("upDown")) {
            leftValue += leftRandom;
            rightValue -= rightRandom;
        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("downUp")) {
            leftValue -= leftRandom;
            rightValue += rightRandom;
        }

        this.leftLabel.setText(Integer.toString(leftValue));
        this.rightLabel.setText(Integer.toString(rightValue));
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Write a WidgetViewer GUI that has the following widgets:
>
> a button labeled "go up/down" a label initialized to 0 (we'll call
>   this the left label) a label initialized to 0 (we'll call this the
>   right label) a button labeled "go down/up"
>
> When the "go up/down" button is pushed, a random number between 1 and
>   10 (inclusive) is generated and added to the left label, and another
>   random number between 1 and 10 (inclusive) is generated and subtracted
>   from the right label.
>
> When the "go down/up" button is pushed, a random number between 1 and
>   10 (inclusive) is generated and subtracted from the left label, and
>   another random number between 1 and 10 (inclusive) is generated and
>   added to the right label.

So, there's a bunch of important things we need to take away from this.

- The values are initially initialised to 0
- You need to update a label when a button is triggered
- Depending on which button is triggered, will determine which values is added or subtracted to

So, we could simply start with

```
class IncrementDecrementAction implements ActionListener {

    private final JLabel leftLabel;
    private final JLabel rightLabel;

    private int leftValue = 0;
    private int rightValue = 0;

    public IncrementDecrementAction(JLabel leftLabel, JLabel rightLabel) {
        this.leftLabel = leftLabel;
        this.rightLabel = rightLabel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        leftValue += rand;
        rand = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        rightValue += rand;
        this.leftLabel.setText(Integer.toString(leftValue));
        this.rightLabel.setText(Integer.toString(rightValue));
    }
}
```

Okay, but this only solves the problem in one direction, what about down/up?

Well, we could write a second `ActionListener` which dealt with that, but then you'd need some kind of model to maintain the left and right values so both listeners knew what the current value was.  Not an unreasonable idea, but it's an extra two classes to make it work.

Instead, we can take advantage of the `ActionEvent`'s `actionCommand` support and give each button a specific name, which we can lookup when the action is triggered...

```
class IncrementDecrementAction implements ActionListener {

    private final JLabel leftLabel;
    private final JLabel rightLabel;

    private int leftValue = 0;
    private int rightValue = 0;

    public IncrementDecrementAction(JLabel leftLabel, JLabel rightLabel) {
        this.leftLabel = leftLabel;
        this.rightLabel = rightLabel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        int leftRandom = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        int rightRandom = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("upDown")) {
            leftValue += leftRandom;
            rightValue -= rightRandom;
        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("downUp")) {
            leftValue -= leftRandom;
            rightValue += rightRandom;
        }

        this.leftLabel.setText(Integer.toString(leftValue));
        this.rightLabel.setText(Integer.toString(rightValue));
    }
}
```

This basically changes the direction of the calculation based on the source of the event - and it does it without having to now what the source of the event actually was (a button, a menu item, a key binding), it just doesn't care.

You simply set this up by applying the appropriate `actionCommand` to the appropriate `Jbutton`, for example...

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private JLabel leftLabel;
    private JLabel rightLabel;

    private JButton upDownButton;
    private JButton downUpButton;

    public TestPane() {
        leftLabel = new JLabel("0");
        rightLabel = new JLabel("0");

        upDownButton = new JButton("Up/down");
        downUpButton = new JButton("Down/up");

        upDownButton.setActionCommand("upDown");
        downUpButton.setActionCommand("downUp");

        ActionListener actionListener = new IncrementDecrementAction(leftLabel, rightLabel);

        upDownButton.addActionListener(actionListener);
        downUpButton.addActionListener(actionListener);

        add(leftLabel);
        add(rightLabel);

        add(upDownButton);
        add(downUpButton);
    }

}
```

Now, I went through a dozen or so ideas before getting to this point - my point was to try and keep it as simple as I could without trying to introduce a whole bunch of complexity which might not need to be added - be beware - I don't know what the intention of the exercise is, so I might have gone in the wrong direction from the one your instructor was trying to get you to do

Comment: This is just about right, i implemented what you had but i still get an error for some reason about have a null pointer exception, im not sure whats wrong. Something is wrong when i add the widget viewer, the left label is messing up the GUI output

Comment: @StavrosBannoura Since `WidgetViewer` is a none standard component to which we don't have the source code, this is the best you can expect - the code runs fully from in my test code

Comment: I noticed, thats why i made some alterations. Thank you for the help @MadProgrammer